# stop swapping img src at set variable number

Tags: javascript, jquery

quick and probably easy jQuery/JS question.
I'm swapping an image src on a loop. The image files all use a number as a file naming convention.  I'm trying to loop through up to the number nine then start the loop at 0 again.
Here's my javascript code:

```
    var i = 0;

    setInterval(function(){
    $('#loop').attr('src', 'http://wx.wpri.com/weather/radar/Radar_Loop_WEB300_00'+ (++i) + '.jpg');
}, 500);
```

Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the modulus operator, or reset it:

```
setInterval(function(){
    i++;
    if (i == 10) { i = 0; }
    $('#loop').attr('src',
        'http://wx.wpri.com/weather/radar/Radar_Loop_WEB300_00'+ i + '.jpg');
}, 500);
```

Or:

```
 setInterval(function(){
    i = (i + 1) % 10;
    $('#loop').attr('src',
        'http://wx.wpri.com/weather/radar/Radar_Loop_WEB300_00'+ i + '.jpg');
}, 500);
```